# Django Admin добавление ссылки в header

Tags: python, django

Нужно в хедер django админки добавить ссылку, которая будет перенаправлять на определенный сайт. Ссылку нужна сделать типа "открыть сайт". Как можно это сделать и реализовать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]